# Moving the entire window with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've been trying to understand the effect presented on this site - http://artofflightmovie.com/ for navigation. They've been using the [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin to move to different parts of the page. However, I cant understand how are they moving the entire screen  to the dom element. Do they have a big background and are they using something like `$(...).scrollTo( {top:'110px', left:'290px'}, 800 );` at each click? Any insights on how I can accomplish something similar would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: They are jumping the viewport to different coordinates within the DOM using anchor tags, then animating a the parallax effect immediately afterwards.

Comment: Try to zoom out.....u will find that they have DIV's Spreadout in Container Div, when you scroll they scroll Container div to make the Div corresponding to Tab Visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Layout  :

Body Size 1200px x 30000px, It have 7 Div's spread out in body at different absolute positions, each Div have an corresponding Tab.

> Animation :

They have handled `onScroll` Event of main div i.e container. Now when you scroll it shows an effect of scrolling on Body, when you reach to next Div to be displayed the tab selection is changed. When you click on any Tab it navigates to it's correspoding Div, changing Conatiner Div's Scroll position as well.